# How to prove $[x,p]=i$ $\implies$ $[x,p^n]=inp^{n-1}$?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

How to prove $[x,p]=i$ $\implies$ $[x,p^n]=inp^{n-1}$?

I can do this using $p=i\frac{d}{dx}$, but my book hasn't introduced this yet so is there another proof without using this ?
These are just linear operators acting on a hilbert space.

Comment: It should be $\displaystyle{\large p = -{\rm i}\,{{\rm d} \over {\rm d}x}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hint: based upon the dependence upon $n$ in your answer, a proof by induction is probably the way to go. Your induction hypothesis should be:
$[x,p^n] = inp^{n-1}$ and you want to use this property to prove that $[x,p^{n+1}] = i(n+1)p^n$. To see how these are related, note that

$$\begin{eqnarray}[x,p^{n+1}] &=& xp^{n+1}-p^{n+1}x\\
&=& (xp^n)p-p(p^nx) \\
&=& (xp^n)p-(p^nx)p+(p^nx)p-p(p^nx) \\
&=& (xp^n-p^nx)p+p^n(xp-px).\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: nice answer. I would just add we can see this from the ever useful quantum mechanical identity $[A,BC] = B[A,C]+[A,B]C$ taking $A=x$ and $B=p^n$ and $C=p$. I think it's fair to say this is how you added zero.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook yeah that's what I had in mind, though of course it's not limited to just quantum mechanical operators but holds more generally in any Lie algebra.

Comment: @CameronWilliams You probably don't mean "in any Lie algebra", because a Lie algebra would have the brackets but not the ordinary products (like $BC$). I think this argument really needs an associative algebra, with the bracket defined, from the product, as the commutator.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oh duh. I sometimes forget it needs to be an associative algebra as well.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Use $\ds{\bracks{A,BC} = B\bracks{A,C} + \bracks{A,B}C}$.

> \begin{align}
> \bracks{x,p^{n}}&=\bracks{x,pp^{n - 1}} = p\bracks{x,p^{n - 1}}
> + \bracks{x,p}p^{n - 1}=p\bracks{x,p^{n - 1}} + ip^{n - 1}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
\bracks{x,p^{n}}&=p\braces{p\bracks{x,p^{n - 2}} + \ic p^{n - 2}} + ip^{n - 1}
=p^{2}\bracks{x,p^{n - 2}} + 2\ic p^{n - 1}
\\[3mm]&=\cdots=p^{k}\bracks{x,p^{n - k}} + k\ic p^{n - 1}
\end{align}

> With
>   $\ds{k = n - 1\,,\quad
> \bracks{x,p^{n}} = p^{n - 1}\bracks{x,p} + \pars{n - 1}\ic p^{n - 1}}$:
>   $$
> \color{#00f}{\large\bracks{x,p^{n}} = \ic np^{n - 1}}
> $$